# i want to search for a specific payment in arraylist of object by the id number and display it

Tags: java

In main

```
Invoice r = new Invoice();
r.addpayment(new  Payment("cash", 333, 20000.0,date2, "villa"));
r.addpayment(new Payment("cash",9000, 30000.0,date2, "apartment"));
r.getPayment(333);
```

Here I should use this method to return the object which is all payment information

```java
public class Invoice
{
    ArrayList<Payment> payments = new ArrayList<Payment>();
    public Payment getPayment(int paymentId)
    {
        for (Payment temp: payments)
        {
            if (temp.getPaymentId() == paymentId)
            {
                return temp;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

but it didn't return anything :(

`addpayment` method to add new payment to the system:

```java
public void addpayment(Payment payment)
{
    payments.add(payment);

    System.out.println("payment has been added ");
    for (int i = 0; i < payments.size(); i++)
    {
        System.out.println("payment Type : " + payments.get(i).getPaymentType() + " \npayment id : " + payments.get(i).getPaymentId() +
                " \npaymen price : " + payments.get(i).getPrice() + "\npayment description: " + payments.get(i).getDescription() +
                "\n payment date :" + payments.get(i).getPaymentDate() + "\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it didn't return anything"? Does the program hang? Does it return null?

Comment: it didn't print anything at all

Comment: Have you added anything in the payment Arraylist as it seems to me It is empty

Comment: Why not post the code to the method `addpayment`. And the `Payment` class constructor at least.

Comment: Well Your arraylist is empty as you didn't saved anything in that arraylist. All you are doing is just declaring it.

Comment: First of all, write down all your code, so all can understand. Add your Payment class and all the other code that you're using.

Comment: try printing the Payment arraylist size and its content when you are traversing the arraylist to ensure the fields are present

Comment: i just need to add .toString hhh thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are not printing the returned `Payment` object.

Replace

```
r.getPayment(333);
```

with

```
System.out.println(r.getPayment(333));
```

Make sure you have overridden `toString` in `Payment` something like:

```
@override
public String toString() {
    return "Payment type: " + paymentType + ", Payment id: " + paymentId + ", Paymen price: " + price + ", Payment description: " + description + ", Payment date: " + paymentDate;
}
```

in order to get a meaningful output.

Check [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--) for more information.

Comment: that would return a list object and not the value, it would be something like this "Payment@27973e9b" .

Comment: @Vignesh_A - it will return a `Payment` object, not a `List`. Check the definition of the method, `getPayment` in the question. And, when you say, **it would be something like this "Payment@27973e9b"**, you are yourself contradicting your statement. Note that it will print like `Payment@27973e9b` when the `toString` method in `Payment` is not overridden appropriately. Check [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--) for more information.

Comment: I meant to say that, it would return a payment object and if there is no toString() being overriden , it would print something like this " System.out.println(r.getPayment(333)); ---- > Payment@27973e9b" (The object).

Sorry for the typo "List object" , *its an object

Comment: No worries...wish you all the best!

Answer (score 0):

Print the value being returned by checking null and print it

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    class Payment{
    private String price;
    private String paymentType;
    private String paymentDate;
    private String description;
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    public String getPaymentDate() {
        return paymentDate;
    }
    public void setPaymentDate(String paymentDate) {
        this.paymentDate = paymentDate;
    }
    public Integer getPaymentId() {
        return paymentId;
    }
    public void setPaymentId(Integer paymentId) {
        this.paymentId = paymentId;
    }
    private Integer paymentId;

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
    public String getPaymentType() {
        return paymentType;
    }
    public void setPaymentType(String paymentType) {
        this.paymentType = paymentType;
    }
    public Payment( String paymentType,String price,  Integer paymentId, String description) {
        super();
        this.price = price;
        this.paymentType = paymentType;
        this.description = description;
        this.paymentId = paymentId;
    }

        @Override
public String toString() {
    return "Payment [price=" + price + ", paymentType=" + paymentType + ", paymentDate=" + paymentDate
            + ", description=" + description + ", paymentId=" + paymentId + "]";
}


}


public class Invoice
{
    ArrayList<Payment> payments = new ArrayList<Payment>();
    public Payment getPayment(int paymentId)
    {
        for (Payment temp: payments)
        {
            if (temp.getPaymentId() == paymentId)
            {
                return temp;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void addpayment(Payment payment) {
        payments.add(payment);

       System.out.println("payment has been added ");
       for(int i=0; i<payments.size();i++) {
           System.out.println("payment Type : "+ payments.get(i).getPaymentType()+ " \npayment id : " + payments.get(i).getPaymentId() + 
                   " \npaymen price : " + payments.get(i).getPrice() + "\npayment description: " +payments.get(i).getDescription()+
                   "\n payment date :"+payments.get(i).getPaymentDate()+"\n");
       }


   }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Invoice r = new Invoice();
        r.addpayment(new  Payment("cash", "333", 20000, "villa"));
        r.addpayment(new Payment("cash","9000", 30000,"apartment"));
        System.out.println(r.getPayment(20000));
    }

}
```

Comment: i added in the main

Comment: Seems there is some confusion about `this`